# Counting valency of atoms, in a molecule with python

Tags: python, modeling

The documentation for the indigo module can be found here

http://ggasoftware.com/opensource/indigo/api#inputoutput

So for instance if I have a molecule object for some SMILES string, e.g. `"[C](=[O])"`, I wish to calculate the valency of each atom, for instance here the desired output would be `[atom=C, unbound_electrons=2],[atom=O, valency=0]`

If I consider the atom `"[C]"`
Can anyone explain why is this code printing `[atom=C, unbound_electrons=0]` not `[atom=C, unbound_electrons=4]`

```
from indigo import *
indigo = Indigo()

mol=indigo.loadMolecule("[C]")

print(mol.grossFormula(),"\n")

for atom in mol.iterateAtoms():
        print([atom.symbol(),atom.radicalElectrons()])
```

EDIT: I could work it out if I could generate a list of the types of bonds on the atom in conjuction with `atom.atomicNumber()`. E.g. if I could say `[C]` has a double bond I could take it's atomic number - 2 (second shell) - 2 (double bond)

EDIT#2: This might be useful for visualising what i'm talking about

```
from indigo_renderer import *
renderer = IndigoRenderer(indigo)
renderer.renderToFile(mol,"mol.png")
```

EDIT#3: I am not a chemist, so might have got some concepts wrong

Comment: What is being printed out?

Comment: @Jim: I have updated it to include that

Comment: I don't think this is a python problem.  Have you tried other molecules?  Maybe your format is wrong or not what you really want.

Comment: It works some of the time, for instance '[O](=[C](-[C](-[H])(-[H])(-[O])))' works, but "[C](-[H])" doesn't..

Comment: Carbon had 4 valence electrons, so I think it's giving you the unbound *valence* electrons.  So `[C](-[H])` should give Carbon as having 3 unbound valence electrons and Hydrogen as none.

Comment: "[C](=[O])" returns valence 4 for carbon and 2 for Oxygen
"[C](-[O])" returns valence 1 for carbon and 2 for Oxygen, this seems inconsistent!